# OnClick check, remove & add class name in angular13

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to add the class name 'active' onClick to 'li a' & also remove any 'active' class present on the 'li a'. The current code is working properly if I click sequence from top elements, but when I click elements from bottom to top, it's not working.

1. component.html

```
<div class="container text-center">
  <ul id="myList" class="pt-5">
    <li class="p-3">
      <a href="#" class="d-inline-block" (click)="linkActive($event)">List 1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="p-3">
      <a href="#" class="d-inline-block" (click)="linkActive($event)">List 2</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

2. component.ts

```
linkActive(event) {
    const activeClass = event.srcElement.classList.contains('active');
    const classFound = document.querySelector('li a');
    const hpn = classFound.classList.contains('active');
    if (activeClass == true) {
      if (hpn == true) {
        classFound.classList.remove('active');
      }
      alert('true');
      event.srcElement.classList.remove('active');
    } else {
      if (hpn == true) {
        classFound.classList.remove('active');
      }
      alert('false');
      event.srcElement.classList.add('active');
    }
  }
```

Please find the sample code : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jf9xvp

Comment: You shouldn't manipulate DOM directly to do this kind of thing.

Comment: I am new to this, let me know what to change and make it work

Comment: I suggest you reading the heroes tutorial on angular docs.

Answer (score 0):

Do not manipulate the DOM directly like this,
You can use [ngClass](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) to achieve the desired result:

template:

```
<a href="#" class="d-inline-block" [ngClass]="{'active': activeList === 1}" (click)="linkActive(1)">List1</a>
```

.ts

```
public activeList: number;
```

...

```
public linkActive(listNumber: number) {
   this.activeList = listNumber; 
}
```

In general, as recommended in comments, do the [heroes tutorial](https://angular.io/tutorial) and try to understand how to use typescript.